# Generic method for both IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I was trying to make a generic method for paging both `IEnuemrable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`

Like this:

```
public T Paginate<T, TS>(T list) where T : IEnumerable<TS>
{
    CheckValidityAndClamp();
    return (T)(list.Skip(Page*PageSize).Take(PageSize));
}
```

When I passed in a `List<int>` instance it compiles fine.
But when run it gives a cast exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException : An object of type '<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Int32]' can not be converted to the type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.
```

Why is that? A `List<int>` implements `IEnumerable<int>` so why the cast exception?

Comment: Can you show the calling code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not returning a list.  `Take` is implemented with an iterator block, which means that the actual type is a type with no compile time identifier (which is why it looks so weird) and it implements `IEnumerable`.  It is not a `List`, which you're trying to cast it to.

On top of that, your method *can't* actually work for any `IQueryable` objects.  It's calling the implementation of `Skip` that accepts an `IEnumerable` (because that's what the generic constraint tells the compiler it must implement) so if it were an `IQueryable` (even if you resolved the messy cast issue) you wouldn't be using the query provider to translate the `Skip` call.  You need to have two overloads here, one for `IQueryable` and one for `IEnumerable`; this is pretty much inherent to the problem given that there are two `Skip` and `Take` methods that you need to call, one for each of `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks! I also ended with two overloads. Good to know the reason behind.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Servy's (correct) answer - another issue is that `Skip` and `Take` are extension methods, which is syntactic sugar for calling static methods.  Since static methods are bound at compile time, the best information that the compiler has is that `T` is an `IEnumerable<TS>`, so the compiler binds `Skip` and `Take` to the static methods of `Enumerable`.  There's no way to dynamically bind static methods at run-time.  That is why there are two different classes for the extension methods on `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` (`Enumerable` and `Queryable`)

You need two overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. Great info.

Answer (score -1):

You get this as you cannot cast the IEnumerable to List (This is why LINQ has .ToList() extension). I think what you want is something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Paginate<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return list.Skip(Page * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
}
```

Which will work with any source that implements IEnumerable (List, T[], IQueryable)

You can then call it like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> list = someQueryResult;
IEnumerable<int> page = class.Paginate<int>(list);
```

As pointed out in other answers. IQueryable has it's own set of extension methods. So all though this will work, the paging will not be done as the data-source, as it will use the IEnumerable extensions

Comment: It will compile, but it will not bind to the `IQueryable` extension methods.

Comment: Indeed. I have updated to make it clearer, however it will both compile and run. But it will not be terribly effective as it will reduce the IQueryable to IEnumerable, thus do the paging on an in-memory collection rather than on the data-source

Comment: @SimonBull So it'll compile and run *but not actually work correctly*.  *That's exactly the problem with your answer; it won't **work*** even if it will compile and not throw an exception at runtime.